# jQuery function to create or set hidden input dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a function which updates the hidden inputs dynamically.

Below is my function:

```
function updateDeletedFileIds(deletedFileId) {
    if($('input[name=multiFieldDeletedIds]') == null) {
        $('.selected_file_info').append('<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="'+deletedFileId+'" />');
    }
    else{
        id = $('input[name=multiFieldDeletedIds]').val();
        id += ','+deletedFileId
        $('input[name=multiFieldDeletedIds]').attr('value', id);

    }
}
```

Here is my expected output: when the `updateDeletedFileIds` function is called for the first time it should create a hidden input tag and set the value as per `deletedFileId`

```
updateDeletedFileIds(1) =>
'<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="1" />'
```

when it is calleda  second time it should just update the value as comma separated

```
updateDeletedFileIds(2) =>
'<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="1,2" />'

updateDeletedFileIds(3) =>
'<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="1,2,3" />'
```

But my function is not working as expected.  Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Can you show your HTML code? What error you are getting? Or what is happening which is not expected by you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether your jQuery selector returned anything, you should check its length property. I also recommend using `val()` as opposed to `attr()` to set the value, as `attr()` only affects the html attribute, while `val()` sets its DOM property.

```
function updateDeletedFileIds(deletedFileId) {
    var $el = $('input[name=multiFieldDeletedIds]');
    if(!$el.length) {
        $('.selected_file_info').append('<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="'+deletedFileId+'" />');
    }
    else if ($el.val().indexOf(deletedFileId) < 0) {
        $el.val($el.val() + ',' + deletedFileId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working ...http://jsfiddle.net/hyvhbs2y/1/   .. remove `+=` and write only `+` in `else`

Comment: @JoshBjelovuk Thanks for the answer I appreciate it. How do I make sure duplicated ids are not added to hidden fields. I mean if `updateDeletedFileIds(1) ` for second time it shouldnt update the hidden fields

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
    function updateDeletedFileIds(deletedFileId) {
        var $el = $('.selected_file_info');
        if($el.find("input.MultiField").length==0) {
            $('.selected_file_info').append('<input type="hidden"  class="MultiField" name="multiFieldDeletedIds" value="'+deletedFileId+'" />');
        }
        else{
          if( $el.find("input.MultiField").val().indexOf(deletedFileId)<0) { 
            $el.find("input.MultiField").val($el.find("input.MultiField").val() + ','+deletedFileId);
        }
      }
    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hyvhbs2y/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I appreciate it. How do I make sure duplicated ids are not added to hidden fields. I mean if `updateDeletedFileIds(1) ` for second time it shouldnt update the hidden fields